# How to read the html tag which is not reflecting in the beautiful soup object

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, hidden, python-beautifultable

I am trying to scrape the pages of anime tv series for my side project and stuck with this small issue where I am not able to extract a complete div tag.

link: https://gogoanime.in/category/boruto-naruto-next-generations

I am trying to scrape this thing here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeNvi.png)

The code I am using is this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


trialURL = 'https://gogoanime.in/category/boruto-naruto-next-generations' 
#completeAnimeList_df.URL[0]
page = simple_get(trialURL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

#working on number of comments
divComment = soup.find('span', attrs={"class" : "comment-count"})
print(divComment.get_text)
```

I am getting a NoneType output after running the code. Please let me know what could be done.

Comment: shouldn't the method read .get_text() ?

Comment: Because the `span/comment-count` is the output from running a `disqus-script` so its returning `NoneType`. Better use selenium to wait and then scrape the data.

Comment: get_text and get_text() both kinda give you same output. 
@Siva - so if I use selenium, you want me to give external wait time?

Comment: You can use sleep in python that waits for specific time period. `driver.get(url);
time.sleep(5);` after which you can try to scrape the data